Filter series in method chain
What is the preferred syntax to filter a polars Series without referencing the Series explicitly? I.e. something that works with method chaining. I thought pipe would be an option but it is not available for Series.
Without method chaining, I would do the following:
import polars as pl

ser = pl.Series([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
ser = ser.filter(ser > 3)


you could use anonymous function for that (lambda x: x.filter(x > 3))(ser). Or convert to dataframe ser.to_frame().pipe(lambda x: x.filter(pl.col('') > 3)).to_series()

https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/issues/13772 is the feature request to allow .filter(pl.element() > 3)

Thank you, I would love to see this feature.

Slight tweak to roman's suggestion - there is no need for the pipe/lambda. ser.to_frame().filter(pl.col('') > 3).to_series() also works
